# При чтении информации из файла читается дополнительный мусор

Tags: c, visual-studio, файлы, codeblocks

Открываю файл для чтения, потом присваиваю num кол-во элеиентов в файле,функция работает,проверял, ставлю курсор в начало,потом выделяю память под указатель структуры emp, куда хочу считать инфу и собственно fread-ом считываю и потом вывожу через цикл,вместе с основной инфой, выводится мусор непонятный, не понимаю что это и как исправить, помогите пожалуйста, скоро сдача работы, а я из-за этого ещё кучу функций проверять не могу![image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbtZL.png)

Внизу ещё функция добавления информации в структуру и файл и сама структура

```
 void output()
{
if((fp=fopen("dob.txt","r"))!=NULL)
{
int num,u;
num = calcItemsCount_credit(fp);
if (num != 0)
    {
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
emp = (struct credit*)malloc(num * sizeof(struct credit));
printf("\n______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n");
printf("|  №  | Договор  | Год заключения|Месяц заключения |День заключения|Тип кредита|Сумма кредита|Срок кредита|Номер филиала|Имя заёмщика|Фамилия заёмщика|Возраст заёмщика|\n");
printf("|_____|__________|_______________|_________________|_______________|___________|_____________|____________|_____________|____________|________________|________________|\n");
for (u = 0; u < num; u++)
{
fread(&emp[u], sizeof(emp[u]), 1, fp);
printf("|%-5d|%2d        |%4d           | %2d              |   %2d          | %9s |    %5d    | %4d(дни)  |   %2d        |  %8s  |    %8s    |     %4d       |\n", u + 1, emp[u].number, emp[u].date.god, emp[u].date.month, emp[u].date.day, emp[u].type, emp[u].sum, emp[u].srok, emp[u].filial, emp[u].info.name, emp[u].info.surname, emp[u].info.age);
printf("|_____|__________|______________ |_________________|_______________|___________|_____________|____________|_____________|____________|________________|________________|\n");
}
fclose(fp);
free(emp);
    }
else
printf("Записей нет\n\n");
}
else printf("Файл не открылся\n");
}




    void dob()
    {
        system("cls");
        if ((fp = fopen("dob.txt", "a"))==NULL)
        {
            printf("Не удалось открыть файл\n");
            getchar();
        }
        a:
        printf("Введите номер договора:\n");
        if (!scanf("%d", &K[i].number))
        {
            printf("Введите число:\n");
            getchar();
            goto a;
        }
        fprintf(fp, "Номер договора - %d  ", K[i].number);
        a1:
        printf("Введите год заключения договора:\n");
        if (!scanf("%d", &K[i].date.god))
        {
            printf("Введите число:\n");
            getchar();
            goto a1;
        }
        else if (K->date.god < 1900 || K->date.god>2019)
        {
            printf("Введите подходящий год:\n");
            getchar();
            goto a1;
        }
        fprintf(fp, "Год заключения договора - %d  ", K[i].date.god);
        a2:
        printf("Введите месяц заключения договора:\n");
        if (!scanf("%d", &K[i].date.month))
        {
            printf("Введите число:\n");
            getchar();
            goto a2;
        }
        else if (K[i].date.month < 1 || K[i].date.month>12)
        {
            printf("Введите число от 1 до 12:\n");
            getchar();
            goto a2;
        }
        fprintf(fp, "Месяц заключения договора - %d  ", K[i].date.month);
        a3:
        printf("Введите день заключения догвора:\n");
        if (!scanf("%d", &K[i].date.day))
        {
            printf("Введите число:\n");
            getchar();
            goto a3;
        }
        else if (K[i].date.day < 1 || K[i].date.day>31)
        {
            printf("Введите число от 1 до 31:\n");
            getchar();
            goto a3;
        }
        fprintf(fp, "День заключения договора - %d  ", K[i].date.day);
    again1:
        printf("Введите один из трёх типов банковского кредита:\n");
        printf("1-Лизинг\n");
        printf("2-Факторинг\n");
        printf("3-Форфэтинг\n");
        if (!scanf("%d", &n1))
        {
            printf("Введите число:\n");
            getchar();
            goto again1;
        }
        else if (n1 < 1 || n1>3)
        {
            printf("Введите число от 1 до 3");
            getchar();
            goto again1;
        }
        switch (n1)
        {
        case 1:
            strcpy(K[i].type, "Лизинг");
            fprintf(fp, "Тип кредита - %s\n", K[i].type); break;
        case 2:
            strcpy(K[i].type, "Факторинг");
            fprintf(fp, "Тип кредита - %s\n", K[i].type); break;
        case 3:
            strcpy(K[i].type, "Форфэтинг");
            fprintf(fp, "Тип кредита - %s\n", K[i].type); break;
        }
        a4:
        printf("Введите сумму выдаваемого кредита:\n");
        if (!scanf("%d", &K[i].sum))
        {
            printf("Введите число:\n");
            getchar();
            goto a4;
        }
        fprintf(fp, "Сумма выдаваемого кредита - %d  ", K[i].sum);
        a5:
        printf("Введите срок кредита в днях:\n");
        if(!scanf("%d", &K[i].srok))
        {
            printf("Введите число:\n");
            getchar();
            goto a5;
        }
        fprintf(fp, "Срок кредита в днях - %d  ", K[i].srok);
        a6:
        printf("Введите номер филиала банка,выдаваемого кредит:\n");
        if (!scanf("%d", &K[i].filial))
        {
            printf("Введите число:\n");
            getchar();
            goto a6;
        }
        fprintf(fp, "Филиал банка - %d  ", K[i].filial);
        printf("Введите имя заёмщика:\n");
        scanf("%s", K[i].info.name);
        fprintf(fp, "Имя заёмщика - %s  ", K[i].info.name);
        printf("Введите Фамилию заёмщика:\n");
        scanf("%s", K[i].info.surname);
        fprintf(fp, "Фамлия заёмщика - %s  ", K[i].info.surname);
        a7:
        printf("Введите возраст заёмщика:\n");
        if (!scanf("%d", &K[i].info.age))
        {
            printf("Введите число:\n");
            getchar();
            goto a7;
        }
        else if (K[i].info.age < 18 || K[i].info.age>150)
        {
            printf("Введите подходящий возраст:\n");
            getchar();
            goto a7;
        }
        fprintf(fp, "Возраст заёмщика - %d  ", K[i].info.age);
            fclose(fp);
            i++;
    }


    struct credit
    {
        struct Date date;
        struct Info info;
        int number;
        char type[30];
        int sum;
        int srok;
        int filial;
    };
    credit K[30];
    credit *emp;
```

Comment: Ничего не понял... файл вроде текстовый, читаете его как двоичный. В файле-то что содержится? А малиновый прямоугольник вы в вопрос поместили для красоты?

Comment: Покажите само определение структуры и функцию как записываете в файл.

Comment: Зачем понадобился массив `emp`? Зачем вы читаете данные в массив, если он потом никому не нужен?

Comment: @freim, в файл записываю в начале работы структуру, когда вывожу, считываю эту структуру через указатель emp и пытаюсь вывести в форме таблицы, малиновый квадрат показывает что выводится, что кроме основного текста показывает какой-то мусор, что я пытаюсь устранитть

Comment: @AlexGlebe, добавил

Comment: @AnT, считываю из файла в указатель emp и потом из него вывожу на консоли
По-другому даже не знаю как

Answer (score 0):

Смотрим *man* по функциям:

*fopen*: r - Открыть **текстовый** файл для чтения.

*fread*: fread, fwrite - ввод/вывод из **двоичного** потока

Т.е. Вы из **текстового** файла пытаетесь что-то читать **двоичными** функциями. Вы уж разберитесь - что у Вас на самом деле!

Comment: Если я везде, к примеру к w добалю b(из w получу wb) и из r -> rb, это решит проблему,нет?

Или подскажите тогда сразу, что делать: записываю и читаю с тектсового файла, fread и fwrite разве не подходят?

Comment: @ЕвгенийПауля *Если я везде, к примеру к w добалю b* - Никто в мире, кроме Вас, не знает - какой там у Вас файл: двоичный или текстовый. Главное, что бы Вы и при открытии и при чтении файла использовали ОДИН и тот же тип.

Comment: ну я так и понимал, вроде такой логикой и руководствовался, для открытия и чтения один тип, только помехи эти при выводе остаются((

Comment: @ЕвгенийПауля *помехи эти при выводе остаются* - Это означает (скорее всего), что Вы используете **текстовый файл** (главный признак - наличие символов перевода строки), а читаете его функцией *read()*, предназначенной для чтения двоичных файлов. Эта функция НЕ понимает символов перевода строки и читает до тех пор|, пока не заполнится буфер. Текстовые файлы лучше всего читать функциями *fscanf()* или *fgets()*.